# Storing CloudWatch Logs into S3 (some structured format)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-athena, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a CloudWatch Log Group, this log group continuously receives logging information from my AWS services.

I want to extract some of the logging information from this log-group and want to store that data into S3 in some format (CSV, PARQUET).

I will then use Athena to query this logging data.

**I want some sort of automatic mechanism to send these logs continuously to S3.**

Can anyone suggest solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Athena is able to communicate directly with cloudwatch as shown [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-athena-query-federation/tree/master/athena-cloudwatch). Not sure how performant this is and how costly this turns out.

The other option is to configure Cloudwatch to send data to Firehose via [Subscriptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html) which then dumps it to S3.

Comment: Yes, Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose is the best way to send 'continuous' data to Amazon S3. It saves in batches, based on time or data size.